# PowerShell script to identify and stop one specific service

Tags: powershell, service, antivirus, identify

I try to make a PowerShell script to do the following:
I want to identify the antivirus running on my PC.

I use command to do that:

```
$AntiVirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -Class AntiVirusProduct 
Write-Output $AntiVirusProduct.DisplayName
```

Here I get the antivirus name but, I don't know how to grep the antivirus name and put it to the next command.
The next command is:

```
Stop-Service -Force "$Antivirus Name"
```

Or if there is a better way to to this?

**Edit**

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\SecurityCenter2 -Class AntiVirusProduct |
    Select DisplayName
```

```
DisplayName
-----------
AVG Antivirus
Windows Defender
```

Comment: `Stop-Service $AntiVirusProduct.DisplayName -Force`? Of course this will only work if the display name returned is actually the name of the service.

Comment: It dosen't work, because the output is like this : Windows Defender
AVG Antivirus and I don't know how to grep only AVG Antivirus without Windows Defender. Stop-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'Windows Defender'.

Comment: The service name doesn't neccessarily match the registered AntiVirusProduct name. Here it doesn't match with Avira. I'd try  `Get-Service *AVG* | Stop-Service -Confirm` or whatever your antivirus is. Please [edit] your question to contain additional information.

Answer (score 1):

If your display name output is a list of service names you can remove the Windows Defender entry from the list with something like this:

```
$svc = $AntiVirusProduct.DisplayName |
       Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*Windows Defender*' }
```

and then stop the service like this:

```
$svc | Stop-Service -Force
```